# Как передать в главный поток строку, получаемую через командную строку?

Tags: c++, строки, указатели, argv, командная-строка

Нужно в программу передать имя файла, получаемое через открытие через командную строку.
file_name должно быть типа стринг

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
if(argc > 1){
    file_name=*argv;

char file_name[]="1.txt";
```

этот код компилируеться, но если убрать последнюю строку, потом ругаеться в команде fin.open(file_name);
нужно чтобы при помощи третьей строки, четветрую можно было бы удалить, потому что имя файла тогда не зависит от того, какое мы передаем в командной строке.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вы такое написали, что не понять...

Вобщем, примерно так:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    string file_name = "1.txt";
    if(argc > 1){
        file_name=argv[1];
```

Т.е. если в командной строке ничего не передано - будет `1.txt`, если передано - то то, что первым параметром в командной строке...